# In Google Analytics, how can I graph direct traffic vs Google referrals?

Tags: google-analytics, reporting

How can I graph direct traffic, versus referals from other search engines (in particular Google)?

I can kind of get what I want by using the "Plot Lines" function, from the Traffic Sources > All Traffic graph, but as the graph includes a line for "all traff" and is scaled as such, it makes it difficult to visualise only the google and direct traffic items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This graph is available in Google Analytics but getting it is not easy.  I figured this out for a similar problem which I blogged about: [Graphing the performance of sub-domains](http://blog.ostermiller.org/analytics-subdomain/).   Here are the steps you need to follow:

1. Select the date range that you want.
2. Navigate to "Traffic Sources" -> "Sources" -> "All Traffic"
3. Click on the "Motion Charts" icon (it is three black dots located top right of the graph).  I don't know why some line graphs are hidden under motion charts, it doesn't make sense to me.
4. On the left of the graph change the sideways select from "Pages/Visit" to "Visits"
5. Click the tab icon on the top of graph that has a line on it (there is another line graph icon next to the motion charts icon, but you **don't** want that one)
6. Use the check boxes to the right of the graph to select "(direct) / (none)" and "organic / google".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can do that unless you create advance segment. I would suggest generating separate graphs for both direct and search traffic from traffic sources and compare those graphs to generate one new.