# Compare referrer domains over time in Google Analytics without an "all traffic" line?

Tags: google, google-analytics

I would like to look at my referral traffic over time on a per domain-basis in Google Analytics. This is what I have done:

1. Set New visits as advanced segment
2. Navigated to traffic-sources -> Referrals
3. Checked a coulple of domains
4. Clicked plot rows

The individual domains now show up in the graph, but the problem is that "all traffic" is also visible. All traffic is much bigger than the graphs for individual domains. This makes it very hard to see any changes as they look all values are Zero.

Is there any way to hide "Visists" from the graph in order to zoom in on the vertical axis?

Answer (score 2):

This graph is available in Google Analytics but getting it is not easy.  You don't need to use advanced segments for it though.  I figured this out for a similar problem which I blogged about: [Graphing the performance of sub-domains](http://blog.ostermiller.org/analytics-subdomain/).   I also wrote a similar answer to [In Google Analytics, how can I graph direct traffic vs Google referrals?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/52722/14543)  Here are the steps you need to follow:

1. Select the date range you want.
2. Navigate to "Traffic Sources" -> "Sources" -> "Referrals"
3. Change the number of results per page to enough so that the ones you want to compare are all on the first page of results.
4. Click on the "Motion Charts" icon (it is three black dots located top right of the graph).  I don't know why some line graphs are hidden under motion charts, it doesn't make sense to me.
5. On the left of the graph change the sideways select from "Pages/Visit" to "Visits"
6. Click the tab icon on the top of graph that has a line on it (there is another line graph icon next to the motion charts icon, but you **don't** want that one)
7. Use the check boxes to the right of the graph to select the referrers that you want to compare.

[image]

Comment: Rad, I did not know this! Very buried! Thanks for the share!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to unselect the "all traffic" segment. Currently you are comparing the two. So in the advanced segment menu unselect the "all traffic" segment.

Comment: Nope, when you plot rows you don't use the same lists as advanced segments.

Comment: Read your question wrong. At this time, I don' think it's possible to remove the blue line (visits). If you want the chart more to scale, you can try looking at bounce rates or conversion rates. Or, exporting the data to excel and manually removing visits.